# How I can get text in chrome whit the object clonning?

Tags: automationanywhere

I´m trying to extract some info from a web page in google chrome, more exactly the id and the gender, but when I try OCR or object clonning I cant get the right field or get empty field. A table contains the info that I need but the exactly field i can't get it.

please help.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome, copy the Xpath of the object and then then put the Xpath in object cloning field. then the object can be accessed using xpath